# Reading text in python weird error

Tags: python, xml, file, text, file-io

I'm opening a file looking like this: http://pastebin.com/ucH5ayHa

And trying to read it using simple python:

```
f1 = open("goldstandard-answer-utf-8.txt", "r")

print f1.readline();

for line in f1:
    print line

f1.close()
```

Neither print line prints the entire document. Both readline and the for loop separately just prints:

```
</file>
```

This is weird. Obviously it has something to do with the tags in the document but both my attempts at parsing it with either lmxl etree or beautiful soup gave similar results. Is there any way to force python to print the lines and disregarding the tags, if that makes sense?

**Edit:** (Suggested by comments to include) The expected output would be exactly the same as the pastebin entry:
     2028.htm.txt
    Mäkitalo, Östen Mäkitalo, Östen Mäkitalo, Jessica Lindbäck, Östen Mäkitalo, Östen Mäkitalo, Robert Brännström
    etc...

Comment: Can u attach ur text file ??

Comment: I can't share the entire file, sorry. But look at pastebin for an example of how it is constructed. Every new column has the exact same structure.

Comment: I saw another (now deleted) comment suggesting:
    with open("goldstandard-answer-utf-8.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            print line

This gives the same results..

Comment: You better to add some sample input line and expected output and make the question more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I added a bit more to the question about the expected output.

Comment: yes U need to give clear sample input .. u can give any sample which gives same output

Comment: Your attempts at parsing that file with lxml should fail because the document is not a valid XML document due to there being additional content at the end of the file, i.e. an extra (and unclosed) `<file>` tag. As to the weirdness when reading the file as above, it is so weird that I can't believe your observations.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The sample input is in the pastebin. Running the above script doesn't print the content back, that's the problem. 

If I add text without tags at the top of the file it prints those lines as expected.

Comment: @mhawke The file is a lot longer and the pastebin is cut off mid-column so the file-tag is ended. And I agree that it is weird.

Comment: Please remove `Solved` from your title and post the soltuion you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file really is encoded in utf-8, as its name suggests, try opening it as such:

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open('goldstandard-answer-utf-8.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I fixed that by just saving it as utf-8. Now it prints the entire file!

Comment: You're welcome! There's a bit of documentation about Python and unicode here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html